# Делаю программу для генерации рандомных букв из списка, в итоге ошибка, не понимаю в чем проблема

Tags: python

```py
import random

stroka = input('Введи буквы для генерации списка : ')
dlina = int(input('Введи длину генерации : '))
liststroka = list(stroka)
generimone = random.shuffle(liststroka)
generimtwo = ''.join([random.choice(generimone) for x in range(dlina)])
print(generimtwo)
```

В итоге ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.6/Egoroff_Chanel/Learning python/Learning_Egoroff.py", line 516, in <module>
    generimtwo = ''.join([random.choice(generimone) for x in range(dlina)])
  File "D:/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.6/Egoroff_Chanel/Learning python/Learning_Egoroff.py", line 516, in <listcomp>
    generimtwo = ''.join([random.choice(generimone) for x in range(dlina)])
  File "C:\Users\Stan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py", line 288, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не актуально, разобрался
 ошибка была здесь:

```py
generimone = random.shuffle(liststroka)
generimtwo = ''.join([random.choice(generimone) for x in range(dlina)])
```

а должно быть:

```py
random.shuffle(liststroka)
generimtwo = ''.join([random.choice(liststroka) for x in range(dlina)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import random
stroka = input('Введи буквы для генерации списка : ')
dlina = int(input('Введи длину генерации : '))
liststroka = list(stroka)
generimone = liststroka
random.shuffle(generimone)
print(generimone)
generimtwo = ([random.choice(generimone) for x in range(dlina)])
print(generimtwo)
```

В вашем примере `generimone == None`.

Comment: спасибо, уже решено ;)